# set data filter using "struct sflt_filter" for both TCP and UDP protocol

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, tcp, udp

I have used `struct sflt_filter` which is part of `kpi_socketfilter.h`, to set filter for individually for either TCP or UDP protocol which is working fine.

But I want it for both TCP and UDP protocol filter in same program.

This line works for individual call -

```
sflt_register(&sflt_filter_variable, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

I already try

1. registering single "sflt_filter_variable" variable twice.

   `sflt_register(&sflt_filter_variable, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);`
   `sflt_register(&sflt_filter_variable, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);`
2. creating another variable of "struct sflt_filter" and registering it separately as above.

So how can I register filter for both TCP and UDP.
Any help welcomes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got The answer,

Have to change the `sflt_filter_variable.sf_handle` variable value to another 32 bit unique value.

```
sflt_register(&sflt_filter_variable, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

sflt_filter_variable.sf_handle = 0x7a5a5f5d;      // **changed valu of sf_handle.**
sflt_register(&sflt_filter_variable, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

[Hear you can get registered sf_handle values](http://developer.apple.com/datatype/)

OR you can use your own values for now.

[Got At This Link refer this for more referance](http://code.google.com/p/watchfirewall/source/browse/trunk/firewall.cpp?spec=svn9&r=9)